# liferay-ui:tabs not changing active

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-aui

I'm having troubles with liferay-ui:tabs

I need to set an active tab depending on what link was previously clicked. I get this information though an String

```
String selectedTab = ParamUtil.getString(request, "valA", "generalSettings");
```

Then I create the tabs:

```
<liferay-ui:tabs
names="A,B,C,D,E"
tabsValues="valA,valB,valC,valD,valE" refresh="false"
value="<%=selectedTab%>" url="<%=tabURL.toString()%>" param="tab">
<liferay-ui:section>
    <%@ include file="a.jsp"%>
</liferay-ui:section>
<liferay-ui:section>
    <%@ include file="b.jsp"%>
</liferay-ui:section>
<liferay-ui:section>
    <%@ include file="c.jsp"%>
</liferay-ui:section>
<liferay-ui:section>
    <%@ include file="d.jsp"%>
</liferay-ui:section>
<liferay-ui:section>
    <%@ include file="c.jsp"%>
</liferay-ui:section>
```

The problem is that if use **value** parameter I this tab remains actived all the time although when I click other tabs I see the other imports.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give you some hints here. I think you have a two typos.

1. Your parameter is called `tab`, not `selectedTab` (as defined in `param` attribute),
2. your allowed tab values (defined in `tabsValues` attribute) are: *valA, valB* etc.; *generalSettings* is not there.

Try this line:

```
String selectedTab = ParamUtil.getString(request, "tab", "valA");
```

If you just want the first tab to be selected it should be enough to remove `value` attribute of `<liferay-ui:tabs>` altogether. Check [tabs implementation](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/util-taglib/src/com/liferay/taglib/ui/TabsTag.java#L116)- when value is null it'll read parameter `tab` from request itself and select first tab by default when no value is provided.

With `refresh` set to false however you shouldn't get no page refresh that means `selectedTab` will not be initialized with every click on the tab. That's because all sections are pre-rendered on the page and only [Liferay.Portal.Tabs.show](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/js/liferay/portal.js#L30) is [called](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/taglib/ui/tabs/start.jsp#L157) to show the clicked one and hide the others.

Comment: thanks for you help, there were errors because I changed values at the last moment to make it more simple forgetting some stuff. I will be more cautious next time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by creating a RenderURL and to bind it to the url parameter. The only problem that I have now is that every time I change names and tabValues if they are distinct it doesn't show the section content.